# Using optional chaining and array.length invalidates typescript narrowing

Tags: typescript

I just noticed that typescript doesn't know that an variable is not null if I use the length property while narrowing the type:

```
declare const foo: { method: () => void, groups: number[] } | undefined;

if (foo?.groups.length > 0) {
    foo.method();
}
```

That gives you an error saying that object is possibly undefined. If you remove the length check, then it works as expected.
Is this a TS limitation? expected behaviour? bad practice?

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4&ssl=5&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gMyUgXPAN7wC2IGAFksIQBQCU8AvAHzwBuSAlsADTwA5jCQBXAA5pCKUaQBGIGAG0AuvAC%208AD7xRKUNm4oQwANwAoc92zw6uJAH4AdMLGSnEECkFV47AAxMRObwoTh4TuRUNIwW6kA)

Comment: This code has a type error anyway because `foo?.groups.length` can be `undefined`, so it's not necessarily comparable to `0`. In general, Typescript only does type narrowing when the condition has one of a few specific forms, detailed in the docs here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

Comment: How can length on an array be undefined? the groups property is not optional, so as soon as it is not undefined and it is the expected object, groups is an array

Comment: There isn't necessarily an array at all. The expression `foo?.groups.length` will be evaluated to `undefined` if `foo` is undefined. Of course, as soon as it is not undefined then the result is not undefined, but if it *is* undefined then it will be undefined...

Comment: That is not a problem. Undefined is not greater than 0, so the only chance that it evaluates to true is if length is a number and is greater than 0, and at that point foo is defined.

Comment: Yes, `undefined` is comparable to `0` in Javascript, but in Typescript it is a type error because programmers generally don't actually want to compare `undefined` to see if it is greater or less than a number. The error is not anything to do with type narrowing, it is just that you are using a possibly-undefined value to do a comparison with a number. You'd get a similar error if you wrote `let a = 5 + foo?.groups.length;`, because *yes*, Javascript allows you to do `5 + undefined`, but Typescript's job is to tell you that it's probably a mistake if your code can ever do that.

Comment: Consider also if somebody changed this code from `> 0` to `!== 0`, which would make sense if you think this code is comparing a non-negative integer to 0 - and that is a realistic thing a programmer might think about this code, because *you* yourself thought `foo?.groups.length` can't be undefined in your comment 8 hours ago. But if somebody made that change then the code would break because `undefined > 0` is false but `undefined !== 0` is true.

Comment: No, it doesn't invalidate narrowing in this case https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gMyUgXPAN7wC2IGAFksIQBQCU8AvAHzwBuSAlsADTwA5jCQBXAA5pCKUaQBGIGAG0AuvAC+8AD7xRKUNm4oQwANwAoc92zw6uJAH4AdMLGSnEECkFUmRc-CBOHhO5FQ0jBbqQA

Answer (score 0):

In your case if `foo` is `undefined`, `groups` is automatically `undefined`. And you can not compare `undefined` to a number with `>` operator in typescript, because these are two different, incomparable types.

You should use a type guard to ensure `foo` is not `undefined` before you access `groups.length`.

Here's an example of how I do it in my use-case:

```js
type Props = {
  post: {
    tags: string[]
  } | undefined
}
const SinglePost = ({ post }: Props) => {
  // this type guard ensures post is not undefined
  if (!post) return <H1>Not found</H1>
  return (
    ...
      // then you can access length of an underlying array without type errors
      {post.tags.length > 0 && <div>something</div>}
    ...
  )
}
```